# C++ AMP suitable matrix library for inversion, QR decomposition

Tags: c++, matrix, c++-amp, inversion

I require a matrix library for [C++ AMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_AMP) that is able to perform basic operations as well as matrix inversion for arbitrarily sized matrices and QR decomposition.

I initially found that there is a [BLAS AMP implementation](http://ampblas.codeplex.com/), however I could not find anywhere that stated whether or not BLAS can perform matrix inversion, can anyone enlighten me about its capabilities and/or suggest a more suitable parallel matrix library for AMP? Thanks!

**edit**: I found a [LAPACK AMP library](http://amplapack.codeplex.com/) which is capable of matrix inversion (I think), however it's still in development :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, your best bet is the [LAPACK library](http://amplapack.codeplex.com/) that you already linked to. C++ AMP is still fairly new and doesn't seem to have a large uptake in scientific computing so far.

There are also some other C++ AMP libraries in development that may be of interest to you.

1. [Algorithms](http://ampalgorithms.codeplex.com/)
2. [BLAS](http://ampblas.codeplex.com/)
3. [FFT](http://ampfft.codeplex.com/)
4. [Random Number Generation](http://amprng.codeplex.com/)
5. [Generic Kernels](http://ampgenerickernels.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks! looks like I'll write my own parallel inversion method!

Comment: I'm somewhat actively working on the AMP Algorithms library (number 1). I'm not sure that there are a lot of people working on the other libraries but we're always looking for people to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find any LAPACK libraries for C++ AMP.  However, there are some available for OpenCL.

Specifically clMAGMA from the University of Tennessee.

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/software/view.html?id=152

You will need the AMD OpenCL BLAS library to sit under the LAPACK from here:

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-math-libraries/

I think this is your only bet at inverting a matrix with open source libraries on your GPU.  Being openCL, this will be platform agnostic (like C++ AMP), unlike CUDA.

-Matt Musto
www.mustotechnologies.com

Comment: as far as I know C++ AMP is vendor agnostic but not cross platform. it only works on Windows, being a proprietary (not Free/Open-Source) Microsoft API.